# MapKit and Mapbox in a single view controller (two protocols with same method signature, conflict)

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapkit, mapbox

I am trying to implement the Mapbox SDK into my iOS mobile application.
In the app settings, the user can choose between 2 map providers: Apple Maps (MapKit) and Mapbox.
Based on the chosen provider, my view controller adds either a MKMapView or a MGLMapView to the current visible view.

I have a problem because I want to implement the mapView(_:didUpdate:) method. However, this method is present in both MKMapViewDelegate and MGLMapViewDelegate protocols. It seems there is a conflict in my code when I want to have code for both methods in the same viewController class.

How would you design a view controller that could implement both MapKit and Mapbox protocols, if the method signature is the same?

Thanks!
Axel

Comment: you can different this by making your viewcontroller to delegate of either Mapbox or Mapkit. So in that way it will be only call for that class only.

Comment: @Shabir I don't want to duplicate my view controller to have either the MapKit or Mapbox implementation. Also, I am in a situation where the view controller using the map is the app main view controller. So if the user changes the map provider from the settings, I need a way to update the map. Using another class for the view controller is not a solution.

Comment: i am not asking you to use separate class i am just asking to enable/disable delegate on the base of user choice.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I will have to try that to see if the code compiles and if this works as intended. I think I already tested without success but I'll give another try.

Comment: share your code

Comment: @Shabirjan someone suggested another solution here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/8994

Comment: mapboxMapView.delegate = MyViewControllerMGLMapViewDelegate()
        mapkitMapView.delegate = MyViewControllerMKMapViewDelegate()

Comment: This is exactly what i was talking about